# Single Page Application com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, angularjs, single-page-application

Como posso desenvolver uma SPA com jQuery? Fiz com AngularJS com o seguinte código, porém estou tendo dificuldades para migrar para ele em definitivo e decidi me manter com jQuery para não me atrasar.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/:acess', {
templateUrl : 'sources/default.html',
controller  : 'myapp-controll'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/welcome' });
});

myapp.controller('myapp-controll', function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.templateUrl = './g_c.php?a='+$routeParams.acess; 
});
```

Este codigo carregava minhas paginas sem precisar sair da pagina original, usando `#`

**Explicando melhor:**

Vamos fingir que existe um ficheiro dessa forma:

```
./pages/ (pasta) ----
index.html (este)   |
                     --/> home.html
                    |
                     --/> produtos.html
```

Ao clicar na `Pagina inicial` ele tem que carregar na div "conteudo" todo o conteudo do arquivo solicitado, ou seja ele teria que pegar apenas o `home` e puxar ele de dentro da pasta `pages` jogando todo o conteudo na div e o carregando por completo.

Mas e ai? se eu quiser compartilhar o link, vou ter que ensinar ao usuario como checar ate ele? Quais botoes clicar? Isso faria com que o site perdesse muitos usuarios e acesso, entäo a resposta é näo!

Ou Seja se eu fornecesse o link `http://meusite/#/produtos/` para alguém, ao acessar ele tem que carregar na div "conteudo" o conteúdo da pagina `produtos` automaticamente, sem precisar clicar em nada.

```
<div id="inicio"><a href="#/home/">Pagina inicial</a> | <a href="#/produtos/">Produtos</a> | </div>

<div id="conteudo">Oi, eu sou a pagina inicial</div>
```

Comment: Que linguagem tem no lado do servidor?

Comment: Uso PHP para tratar meus dados no servidor.

Comment: Está tarde para mim (fuso Europeu). Apaguei a minha resposta pois ficou claro depois da sua ultima explicação que precisa de usar o `.load()`. Vou juntar a sua info na pergunta. Começo a perguntar-me se não seria melhor usar o Angular mesmo e aprender melhor como ele funciona?

Comment: Angular é complicado para mim, eu ate aprenderia mas o tempo é curto. Nao seria possivel o que expliquei em jQuery? @Sergio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, abordagem com [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', hashchanged);
    hashchanged();
});

function hashchanged() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace(/[#\/]/g, '') || 'home';
    $("#conteudo").load(hash + '.html');
}
```

A primeira parte do código vai procurar mudanças no URL. Quando o URL mudar ( e quando carrega a página a primeira vez) a função `hashchanged` vai ser corrida.

Essa função vai filtrar os simbolos `#` e `/` e usar essa informação para carregar outra página usando o [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) do jQuery.

Comment: Perfeito! Pensei que fosse de certa forma mais complicado, esta função entao estaria realizando o conceito de SPA? @Sergio

Comment: @user3163662 SPA quer dizer aplicação de página única, este código faz isso. Porem o Angular seria mais completo (e complexo talvez).

Comment: @user3163662 experimentou a minha resposta? Se tem provlemas com esse plugin faça uma pergunta acerca dele referindo qual a parte que não consegue pôr a funcionar. Se quer uma solução simples acho que a minha resposta chega. Acho que a esta altura já tinha aprendido a usar o Angular e fazer aquilo que o Angular é bom a fazer.

Comment: seu código funcionou perfeitamente, nao valeria a pena alterar todas minhas funçoes pro angulaejs apenas pra ter a SPA sendo que com jQuery conseguimos perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Em jQuery puro é complicado de ser feito, mas como você tem pressa em realizar, talvez seja necessário não utilizar o AngularJS em si, mas procurar por alguma alternativa mais simples e rápida:
https://github.com/c-smile/spapp

Pela descrição do projeto dentro do GitHub, você aprende as poucas linhas que são necessárias para desenvolver a aplicação que você deseja (o roteamento é feito automaticamente, você só precisa definir o nome da página e a url do arquivo a ser renderizado no item do menu).

Comment: a pergunta é específica para jQuery, infelizmente essa resposta não responde à pergunta :/